# language switching not working in Win 7

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

my application has a language switching from german to english (vice versa)
but this switching works in the windows xp but not in win 7.
i am installing the application in the default path specifying it in the constants(path is the default path where the application is installed).

I have created in the FileSystem(Myapplication)--->Application Folder-->lang folder that has both lang_de.xml & lang_en.xml.

on installing the application in win 7, my settings form has a drop down list and contains English & German.When i select and restart my application the form language should change is the behavior of my application, but this not happening in win7(even after restarting it).

using win forms .net 4.0 c#

thanks in advance

selection from the dropdown list

```
 public string Language
    {
        get
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cmbLang.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (m_strAvailableLanguages[i, 1] == (string)cmbLang.SelectedItem)
                {
                    return m_strAvailableLanguages[i, 0];
                }
            }
            return "de";
        }
        set
        {

            cmbLang.SelectedItem = " ";

            for (int i = 0; i < cmbLang.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (m_strAvailableLanguages[i, 0] == value)
                {

                    cmbLang.SelectedItem = m_strAvailableLanguages[i, 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

save to xml...

```
 private void SaveOptionsValue()
```

{

```
      //........
       //.........
        Config.LanguageShort = this.Language;
        Config.Save();
```

}

```
public void Save()
    {
        m_xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

        XmlNode xmlRoot;
        xmlRoot = m_xmlDocument.CreateElement(ROOT);
        m_xmlDocument.AppendChild(xmlRoot);



        AddNode(ROOT, SYSTEM_LANGUAGE, systemLanguage);
        AddNode(ROOT, LANGUAGE, strLanguage);
           ...............
            ............
```

}

Comment: do you want to change the language based on the one the user selects in the dropdown list?

Comment: @Srinivas yes..but that change affects only after restarting the application.

Comment: How do you persist the setting? Are you sure it is stored and retrieved correctly after the restart?

Comment: @Bond i am trying to saving these options to an xml. And this is working with win xp but not win 7

Comment: @roopinin - so the xml is not updated properly when you close the app? please provide the code that writes/reads the settings of the xml file.

Comment: @Bond yes here is the code that saves to xml file